# How to change the modified time stamp of files in a jar with a Tycho build

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I have a Tycho build that builds some plugins. I need to configure the build so that it is reproducible - meaning the created artifacts of different build runs have to be identical.

For my build, this is currently not the case. The differentes of 2 build runs artifact's is the meta data of the files in the jar's. The "Modified" timestamp is different for every build.

So my question is: Does Tycho provide a way to set the modified timestamp to a specific value? Or is there another way do do this?

[image: Image of the modified timestamp in the jar]

Comment: Why do you care about the "Modified" time? What problems do different timestamps cause?

Comment: @jFabianMeier the problem is that the different timestamps changes the jars on a binary level. So when i compare the two jars that are the same, it tells me they are not the same because the metadata - the modified timestamps - are different

Comment: And why is this a problem? Why not compare them, but ignore differences in the modified date?

Comment: @jFabianMeier I don't know how to ignore the modified date. I kind of assume that this wouldn't help. All jars end up in an RPM and the checksum of this need to match any other RPM checksum of the same build. I think this can only work with exactly the same binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it now. The maven plugin reproducible-build-maven-plugin does exactly what i need:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.zlika</groupId>
    <artifactId>reproducible-build-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>strip-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```